# Stein and Shakarchi Chapter 3 Ex. 7

Tags: real-analysis

Here is the problem:

> Let $E$ be a measurable subset of $[0,1]$. Suppose there exists some $\alpha>0$ such that
>   $$
> m(E\cap I)\geq\alpha m(I)\;\;\text{for any interval }I\subset[0,1].
> $$
>   Show that $m(E)=1$.

**My ideas so far:**

I want to argue via contradiction, and using density points. Suppose that $m(E)<1$. Then $m(E^c)>0$, so $E^c$ must contain a density point, call it $x$. Then (by definition of density point),
$$
\lim_{\substack{m(B)\to0\\B\ni x}}\frac{m(B\cap E^c)}{m(B)}=1.
$$
I am not sure how to derive a contraction from this point.

Comment: Find a $B$ such that $m(B\cap E^c)\ge 1-\alpha.$ Now look at what happens to $m(B\cap E)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick $x \in (0,1)$ and $\epsilon>0$ small enough so that $[x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon] \subset [0,1]$.

Then $\int_{x-\epsilon}^{x+\epsilon} 1_E = m (E \cap [x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon] ) \ge 2 \epsilon \alpha$. Hence
$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} {1 \over 2 \epsilon} \int_{x-\epsilon}^{x+\epsilon} 1_E \ge \alpha$.

Hence Lebesgue's differentiation theorem shows that $1_E(x) \ge \alpha >0$ for ae. $x$. In particular, $1_E(x) = 1$ for ae. $x$.